# Don't favor generic tag over more specific tags

Tags: feature-request, tags

The question [How to change background color in android app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2748830/608639) uses two tags: [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) and [sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sdk). Notice Stack Overflow favors SDK (generic) over Android (specific):

[image]

The site should use the a more specific tag like Android or iOS, to classify a question; rather than a than generic tag.

Its important to use more specific tags to classify because (1) it helps to properly summarize question on search engines; and (2) the site has a policy [that discourages (prohibits?) tags in the title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/173448). Its hard to tell people to follow site policy when the site mis-classifies the question.

Comment: I was under the impression that SO used the most popular tag in the list.  Could it be skipping it because the tag appears in the title?

Comment: @Paul - you're right. I uploaded a new image with the bells and whistles (including a drop shadow).

Comment: @Jason - SO put the SDK in the title of the web page. It was not present in the title of the question.

Comment: Yes, that is my point.  I checked a few other questions with those tags and it seems to pick the most popular of the top two (or three) tags, skipping any that are actually in the question title already.

Comment: SDK seems like a tag that should be nuked anyway.  It provides 0 relevance without a lot more specific data.

Comment: If your request is just about [tag:sdk], nuking that tag as @Gabe properly suggests would take care of it. If it's more general, what *should* be done there?

Comment: @Deduplicator - sorry for the confusion. Nuking [tag:sdk] is not my request. Somone else suggested it. Classifying and presenting [tag:sdk] when there are more specific tags seems to be a UX issue. I'd like the site to fix the UX issue. Hence the reason for the [tag:support] tag. I'm not sure what to make of the downvotes since this is not an agree/disagree question with the [tag:discuss] tag (I'm assuming its someone who does not know how to use Meta Stack Overflow).

Comment: That's more a [meta-tag:feature-request] (your whole post reads like a confused feature-request already, thus the downvote. Probably.), and *how* should the site fix that? By special-casing it somehow (what about the untold other sub-optimal choices when combining tags?), or by introducing new mechanisms (and what kind?)?

Comment: @Deduplicator - *"...confused feature-request"* - I don't think its confused. I pointed out a problem (use of generic, less useful tags), and I suggested a solution (favor the more more specific tag). Perhpas you don't understand the UX issue. In which case, you should probably sit this one out. *"... How should the site fix that"* - that's for the site to figure out. I'm not a developer or staff. I'm just the messenger.

Comment: The problem is in how to decide which tag is more specific, and you not giving any suggestion for the problem but hand-waving it away. I thought my second comment was clear enough about that... If you say you only want to point out there's potential for improvement, well, that should be known. But it doesn't really make for much of a *useful* post.

Comment: @Deduplicator - I tried to improve the support request. I also added reasons the UX problem should be fixed. If you feel it has gaps, then please edit it to suit your taste.

Comment: @Deduplicator - *"The problem is in how to decide which tag is more specific, and you not giving any suggestion for the problem"* - right. Its not my place to tell the site how to do something. Its up to the staff and developers to decide how to do it. If you want to suggest ***HOW*** it should be done, then it might be a useful new question. But I'm staying out of the discussion since I don't have a dog in that fight (i.e., I'm not staff or a developer).

Comment: I want to know... is that question really related to [sdk]?

Comment: Not a bug. You're asking for a change to existing deliberate behaviour. Ergo, feature-request.

Comment: @Anna - it may be existing behavior, but its broken behavior. Ergo, its a bug.

Comment: @jww For what it's worth, I'm retagging this to *help* you get this addressed. As a bug, this is likely to just get status-bydesigned.