# Please block links to imgur and flickr

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, images

Occasionally we get question with resources on other site, like images on Imgur and Flickr.

When editing those questions to inline the image, the *Image* dialog often cannot retrieve the image using the URL in the question. Here's a concrete example of one of those images that could not be retrieved: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDLLS.jpg (from [ListView customization on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27624651/608639)).

Trying to right click and save the image often results in who-can-be-more-clever because those sites want to keep the image, generate more traffic, and generate ad clicks.

Please stop allowing folks to put resources like images on other sites like Imgur and Flickr because its aggravating to people who try to fix questions. In the case of Imgur, only allow URLs from stack.imgur.com.

Or, implement another solution to the problem for folks who improve questions.

---

*Updated, Related*: here's a Meta.SE question on the subject: [New users and attaching images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/111388/173448). According to Abby's answer, new users are allowed to attach images on all sites except Stack Overflow, Server Fault, Ask Ubuntu and Super User.

Stack Overflow is kind of unique among its peers in the list because it now has a Triage area. So maybe part of the the solution is to move questions from new users with images to Triage (and still dissuade users from posting stuff on those sites since SO wants the information with the question).

Comment: And more recently, imageshack, which forces you to download the image now. It's sad when the website itself takes longer to load than the image.

Comment: Unless [something has changed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/195927/182513), new users are still restricted from posting images in questions on the trilogy sites + AU, so external links are often the only method for them to provide an image when necessary.  Stack Exchange would need to provide a mechanism to upload to stack.imgr.com for these users.

Comment: Thanks psubsee. I did not know that (or I knew it so long ago I forgot it).

Comment: @psubsee2003 But do these new users need privileges to post images? They should be focused on formulating good questions first, or so that's one argument I've heard. (And the privilege to post images comes at a very low rep.)

Comment: @remyabel posting an **image** is a privilege on the trilogy and AU.  Posting a link to an image is not.  And most questions do not need an image but there are probably enough cases that it would make it more difficult for new users to get their point across if they are completely blocked from posting an image.

Comment: @psubsee - *"posting an image is a privilege on the trilogy and AU. Posting a link to an image is not"* - aren't they equivalent (with some hand waiving)? I can't help but feel both should be allowed, or both should be stopped?

Comment: The ability to actually use the image Markdown in a post is restricted to 10 reputation merely for spam prevention. Disallowing the post to go through when an image is present eliminates a lot of spambots which just give up because the post got rejected. In cases where it doesn't, a *link* to an image is still a lot less irritating than actually seeing the image (especially if it's a porn ad).

Comment: @animuson - with *Low Quality Posts* and *Triage*, I can't help but feel the site should allow both and then send questions with links into one of those queues for approval until the user has demonstrated themselves. This way, you get the QA and it relieves folks from the burden of battling the off-sites.

Comment: @jww Not sure why you think this is a support request, it isn't requesting for help with an existing feature. You are asking for a change to something, that makes this a `feature-request`

Comment: @bluefeet - its a support ticket because I want to get the site involved to fix the problem. Perhaps I should have used bug tag because its an existing feature that does not work properly. But its not a feature request because the system/features are already present.

Answer (score 25):

I disagree.

What you are a suggesting is blacklisting imgur (and flickr? I don't see those often at all). Imgur is not a dangerous site, and if the proper link is used including the actual image and not a link to the page with the image - as in https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVKFk.png as opposed to https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDLLS.jpg - then there are not even any ads or related items.

What are dangerous sites are several *small* image hosting applications. These would never manage to make it to the blacklist, and they are the ones who actively attempt to attack users when they click through.

**Blacklisting imgur would only lead to the prevalence of less desirable image hosting services.**

There is no actual problem here that blacklisting imgur is solving. A link to imgur is not a problem. It is a well known, highly trusted site. While users *need* to include their code and a proper way to reproduce their issue in their questions, providing a "here is how it looks" screen shot on imgur (even if link only) is not a problem.

Comment: *"I disagree."* - no problem (but this is not a discuss question). I'd like support to fix the problem: *"... implement another solution to the problem for folks who improve questions."*. Also: *"... if the proper link is used including the actual image"* - good luck with that. If that was going to work, it would have worked by now.

Comment: @jww - While it is not tagged as a discussion question, the title and body tell a different story. I am sure you are looking for ways to improve the site, but I feel like this is not going to address an actual problem.

Comment: You'll have to forgive my ignorance. I am not sure what is unclear about the problem statement, and the request to support to fix the problem. The request even has a suggestion (otherwise, folks like Deplicator [want to argue incessantly](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280841/608639)).

Comment: @jww - Sorry, not trying to imply anything about you personally. Introducing a feature to blacklist a site is a feature-request, and that feature is what this answer addresses.

Comment: @TravisJ I agree, this is not a support request - the support tag is  request for assistance with one of the site's features.  This is a feature request or a discussion.