# Please fix the Image Editor so it can handle links provided by the hosting service

Tags: support, images, editor

This is related to [Please block links to imgur and flickr](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/281029/608639).

The Image Editor (insert image) dialog cannot retrieve images from the web. For example, this link was posted recently and the image dialog could not retrieve it:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDLLS.jpg (from [ListView customization on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27624651/608639)).

As another example, here's the a link provided by Post Image: http://postimg.org/image/s9fm1zvmd/ (from the question [Excel auto complete dates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27640909/608639)).

The links above are provided by the site to the author. They are *not* provided with links like https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVKFk.png (as someone claims below).

Here is the result when attempting to add an image from the web using the link provided by the site to the author of the question:

[image]

Please fix the broken Image Editor.

In the case of Imgur, the Image Editor should retrieve the "embed code" automatically (thanks @Compass).

Or, engage the various sites where images are placed and ask them to provide links the Image Editor can handle.

Comment: The link you provide is not a link to an image, it's a link to a *webpage* that contains an image. Are you suggesting that Stack Exchange should have to scan webpages to find the appropriate image link within them?

Comment: @ammunision - that's the link provided by the author of the question. You can check the history of the question to verify.

Comment: This isn't a bad idea; it's just badly written.

Comment: @Derek - this is community retribution.

Answer (score 17):

Use a link to the actual image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVKFk.png

Comment: What's your intention here, @jww? You seem to be a bit confused as to how images on Stack Overflow work (and how Imgur works, for that matter); folks are trying to explain things to you, but you're just getting upset.

Comment: *"What's your intention here"* - to use the Image editor to insert images. The links are provided by the author, and they get them from the site. There's no changing the links. Perhaps you could have a talk with folks like Imgur (et al) so they provide links that the Image Editor can handle.

Comment: Imgur provides multiple types of image links on its site already. http://imgur.com/1ugVFeM?tags The direct link works

Comment: @Compass - and how do you propose I get the direct link when editing a question? The site provides the link to the author of the question, and the author of the question provides it in his question. If there's a method to fetch direct links, then perhaps the Image Editor should do it.

Comment: @jww You open the link in a new tab, and select the appropriate link that should be used, and you link to it. The user should also be checking that the image conforms to Stack Overflow standards, not assuming the image is OK to link just based on the fact that it's on Imgur.

Comment: @Compass - I just revisited the two cited links in the question. Neither provide the ***appropriate link*** you are talking about. *"The user should also be checking that the image conforms"* - if that was going to work in practice, then it would have worked by now. You should give up on that pipe dream.

Comment: @jww http://i.imgur.com/7Pwkmp2.png *Get embed codes*. By default, Imgur users get all links to appear when posting. http://i.imgur.com/ZxAVqCr.png

Comment: @Compass - yes, you're right. "Get embed codes" looks deterministic. Its something the Image Editor should be doing. I wish I could upvote you twice.

Comment: @jww except, it probably only works on imgur. What about other image hosting sites? Do you expect SE dev to accomodate this feature to all possible sites?