# Should we ban skitch.com?

Tags: discussion, images, banning

All the content published under **[skitch.com](https://skitch.com)** is now redirecting to https://evernote.com. As such, all the pictures were lost (and aren't available on archive.org either):

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Askitch.com

Related: [Ban ImageShack Images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300232/ban-imageshack-images)

Comment: One day we  should just "come to Jesus" and whitelist stack.imgur.com instead.

Comment: At least no one seems to have used it since 2012. The most recent ImageShack image is in a question from March 22 of *this year*.

Comment: @BSMP 2013 actually, because I did some cleanup of dead images already.

Comment: So if the URL was last used 5 years ago, because the site doesn't even work anymore and so there's no way anyone could create a new link to a now-broken URL, what's the point of blacklisting the domain now? Doing so isn't going to have any effect on any existing posts - at best it'll alert editors to existing links but it'll do so with a confusing error message and just prompt more meta questions...

Comment: @BoltClock You're right. But what about banning https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Aevernote.com, as this happened because of their misbehavior?

Comment: I don't know. I haven't used Evernote in ages, and I'm not sure what evernote.com links tend to be used for these days.

Comment: @Cœur your search yielded for example this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26658302 with images in it hosted on evernote. Doesn't seem to be a problem there... So not sure why we would need to get rid of it?

Comment: I suppose the reason to ban evernote.com would be the same as for any other image hosting service. Basically it boils down to whitelisting only stack.imgur.com as @Makoto suggested.

Comment: @Luuklag good point. So no need for actions for now.

Comment: For all of us who don't know the history, what SO content was published under skitch.com, when (pre-2013), by whom?

Comment: It looks like [Evernote essentially terminated Skitch a couple of years ago](https://techcrunch.com/2015/12/17/rip-skitch/). But note that these URLs don't seem to be from Skitch when it was operated by Evernote, they seem to be from before they were acquired. I don't think it makes any sense to cease Evernote for failing to support URLs created before they controlled the company, five years later and after the associated product is gone. (Of course I think [banning all external URLs is the only safe way to proceed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/55665) so I would block them as part of that)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Please block links to imgur and flickr](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281029/please-block-links-to-imgur-and-flickr)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since the site doesn't exist anymore, there's no point in banning it -- it won't be used in new posts.

Removing links from posts would disrupt them if we don't provide a replacement -- which we cannot do (see e.g. [How do I raise an exception in Rails so it behaves like other Rails exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918373/how-do-i-raise-an-exception-in-rails-so-it-behaves-like-other-rails-exceptions/1918692#1918692): both the link text and the fact that this is a link are integral to the explanation.). So no point in doing that, either.

If the link breaking has made a post invalid (which would probably mean that is was invalid in the first place by not including all critical parts in the post itself), you can flag it for deletion the usual way.

Comment: yeah, but how many downvotes will it take to get something with `112` upvotes to enable the `close` button much less the `delete` button?

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I was talking about NAA/VLQ flags. There's always a custom flag if it's so unusual that all else fails. FYI a custom flag may actually be appropriate because the votes were cast before the link rotted, so if the rotten link made a post invalid, the votes are invalidated, too.